# IntelliJ IDEA jump from interface to implementing class in Java

Tags: java, class, interface, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

Is there some shortcut that would allow me after creating method in an interface, select and jump to implementing class of that interface?

Comment: In most cases there is an arrow on the left of the method/interface to show all the implementing/overriding classes/methods.

Comment: Here is a [list/cheatsheet](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) of all the default key options.  The CTRL + ALT + B was mentioned below.

Answer (score 319, accepted):

Yes, On mac, it is <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>. You will need to move your cursor to the interface name before invoking the shortcut. I'm not sure what's the shortcut in PC, for if you right click the interface name -> "Go To" -> "Implementations"... the shortcut is listed there.

In Windows, it is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>: [JetBrains navigation documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-to-super-method-or-implementation.html).

Comment: In my case go to implementation is typically more often what I want to see, so I swapped Ctrl-B (`Navigate`->`Implementation(s)`) and Ctrl-Alt-B (`Navigate`->`Declaration`)

Comment: In my case: Ctrl-Option-B

Comment: Just in case someone forgets how to go from implementation to interface, it's Ctrl + U

Comment: Just for a side note, it is working on Ubuntu as well.  Ctrl + Alt + B or Ctrl + Alt + Left Mouse Click will take you to the implementation.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for middle-click to jump to the actual implementation method, and if we want to view the interface use a keyboard shortcut? Most of the time wouldn't we want to view the implementation version of the method anyways rather than just the interface?

Answer (score 83):

In addition to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> mentioned above, you can also use the mouse: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + LeftMouseButton to jump directly to implementations.

Comment: This saved my frustration with the new codebase.

Answer (score 21):

If you did <kbd>Command (Mac)</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl (Windows)</kbd>  + `Mouse click` on method you want to navigate to You will be navigated to `interface (Declaration)`

but If you did <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `Mouse click` on method you want to navigate to You will be navigated to `class (Implementation)`    you can use also <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> if you dont want leave keybourd

Comment: ctrl + click is to interface (Not alt)

Answer (score 8):

On OSX you can jump to the implementation with your mouse by using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + Mouse.
(comparable with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse in Eclipse)

Comment: How to change what? What do you mean? Do you want to change the shortcut? In that case see the `Preferences` -> `Keymap` setting.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not know the shortcut for a specific IntelliJ Command, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (or <kbd>Apple</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> on Mac). That will open a pop-up that allows you to search for all shortcuts. Alternatively, you can access it using the `Find Action...` from the `Help` menu.

Moreover, there is the `Default Keymap Reference` also available from the `Help` menu (that among other shortcuts contains the shortcut to the `Find Action...` described above).

Lastly, you can configure your own keyboard shortcuts (and see the current settings) in the `Preferences` -> `Keymap` setting.

Comment: @cellepo Have you tried? You can also find the shortcut to the `Find Action...` in the `Default Keymap Reference`.

Comment: Looked in the help menu... On Intellij 2016.1.3 on Mac, the command that is listed there and works for me instead is Shift+Apple+A.

Comment: For last 4 years this is ctrl + shift + A, probably it was alt before that.

Answer (score 5):

On MacOs: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + (<kbd>option</kbd>) + <kbd>B</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

To go to the declaration of a symbol, press `Ctrl + B`. For example, pressing this on a variable will take the cursor to the variable declaration.

Using it on a class name will open a new tab and take you to the class file. With `⌥ + ⌘ + B` on `MacOS` and  `Ctrl+Alt+B` on [`Windows/Linux`], you can navigate to an `implementation` too.