# In IntelliJ, shortcut to see all decendants of a class/interface?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, intellij-idea, interface

For a given class or interface, is there a way to see all classes or interfaces that ultimately inherit from the selected class? In other words, if I need an instance of Map, I'd like to know which concrete classes are in the library to implement that. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA jump from interface to implementing class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051766/intellij-idea-jump-from-interface-to-implementing-class-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Move pointer on the class name and press **CTRL + ALT + B**

Answer (score 0):

**CTRL + H** is IDEA alternative for Eclipse show class hierarchy **CTRL + T**